Optionalizing parent class properties?
I have this class:
class A {
  prop: string
}

and I have this class:
class B extends A {
  prop?: string
}

I am getting this typeScript error:
Property 'prop' in type 'B' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A'.
  Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2416)


I want to make all of the child class properties that I am inheriting from the parent optional.
So I thought of this solution, create a function that will help TypeScript to understand that.
function OptionalizeParent<T>(cls: T): Partial<T>{
  return cls
}

Then I can use it in the child class like this:
class B extends OptionalizeParent(A) {
  prop?: string
}

But unfortunately, it's not working, it's giving me this type of error:
Type 'Partial<typeof A>' is not a constructor function type.

I know this breaks the Liskov substitution principle But I do want to break it because I don't care about it.
edit: I found an interface provided by typescript called MapConstructor I wonder if this is useful to the solution, just wanted to add this.

So is the property optional or not if you have a variable of type A, e.g. let a:A = new B()? Your types are incompatible and I wonder if your classes are really in a parent-child relationship. What happens if you have a function f(a: A) { ... a.prop ... } and you call it f(new B()) – is a.prop inside the function optional or not?

class B extends B did you mean class B extends A?

@knittl, yes sorry for that, corrected

@knittl, if you create an instance from A, prop will be required, if you create an instance from B, prop will be optional

But what if you use B in place of an A? (see my example with the function call)

@knittl, then it should throw a compile error saying type B is not compatible with type A because prop could be undefined

is a.prop inside the function optional or not?, no, it will be required

I'm confused. By saying B extends A you are telling the compiler "this type is compatible" with the other type. If they are should not compatible, then you must not have one type extend the other. Why do you want to extend in the first place, if your types are different? By extending B from A, you are telling the compiler that every B is an A. If that's not the case, then don't extend

@knittl, I am using nestjs, and I have class-validator and class-transformer. I wrote a DTO class called CreateUserDto. And I created a DTO called UpdateUserDto. the UpdateUserDto is exactly the same CreateUserDto except that all of its properties are optional. so, for the run-time checking, I used the @IsOptional() decorator for all the properties, but I am left with the type that TypeScript expects, it still thinks that propX for example is number, when it should be number | undefined.

Normal, so maybe you want to invert the direction of the parent-child relationship? CreateUserDto extends UpdateUserDto? Your question is akin to asking "I have a parent class with a string property, but I want the same property to be a number in a child class" – that's not going to work

What I wanted to say, is that this kind of pattern is useful in some scenarios, (breaking the Liskov substitution principle).

@knittl, look I asked chat-gpt and it gave me a solution that I tried and it worked, but I don't want to use it because I don't know if it's going to work well in all the angles, I can't push my code to production to it if I am not sure about it. I'll write an answer answering my question, please hold on.

Well, I already told you several cases where this is not going to work and cause problems. You cannot have an IS_A relationship between types, if the subtype actually isn't extending the parent type.

so maybe you want to invert the direction of the parent-child relationship?, probably this is going to work in some cases, but what if B included some additional fields that I don't want in the A class? Create a Base as a shared point?

@knittl, please let me know about my solution bellow if it's good or not, and if you think doing your solution of inverting the direction of the inheritance is better or if my solution bellow is good. Thanks.

See this playground link. If you're willing to lie to TS about what the parent class is, then you can just do it directly with a type assertion (see Direct namespace), or you could write OptionalizeParent to just return its input (see the impl below that).  Of course saying "I don't care about the Liskov Substitution Principle" is fine but you lose type safety (see the example at the bottom). Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

// Utility type to define a constructor type
type Constructor<T = object> = new (...args: any[]) => T

// Utility type to make all properties of a class optional
type Optional<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P]
}

// Function to make a class's properties optional
export function OptionalizeParent<T extends Constructor>(Base: T) {
  return class extends Base {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args)
    }
  } as unknown as Constructor<Optional<InstanceType<T>>>
}

And then you can use it as:
class A {
  prop: string
}

class B extends OptionalizeParent(A) {
  prop?: string // now it works
}

It works as expected, it only allows you to define prop as number, but also as prop? (undefined) as well if you wanted.
Here's a TypeScript playground

• What's the point of having OptionalizeParent return a subclass of Base instead of just Base? • Why did you define Optional instead of using the equivalent Provided?

Uhhh, wait, you had AI write this code? That's against the rules here. Please delete this answer before a moderator does, so you don't get in trouble.

Quite dangerous: return 42 as unknown as string pretends that 42 is a string, while we can clearly see it isn't. Note that your solution doesn't have a B class as child of A, but B as child of a different class. jcalz playground link perfectly shows the problems of such an approach
